# Row Layout in SWT

Tags: java, layout, swt

As I am new to SWT I am struggling with its layouts. 
I want to implement something like this[image]. I chose to use Row layout but when I implemented, there is some unwanted spaces in the sides. [image]
Can anyone please tell me how can I remove those spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer myself. 
while setting row layout to the shell, if we just set it like this:

```
shell.setLayout(new RowLayout())
```

It seems like the system sets some default values to the `marginTop`, `marginLeft` etc which is the reason while I got some unwanted spaces at the left and top of widgets.

What you need to do is to set those values to `0`.

```
 RowLayout rowLayout = new RowLayout();
 rowLayout.wrap = false;
 rowLayout.pack = false;
 rowLayout.justify = true;
 rowLayout.type = SWT.VERTICAL;
 rowLayout.marginLeft = 0;
 rowLayout.marginTop = 0;
 rowLayout.marginRight = 0;
 rowLayout.marginBottom = 0;
 rowLayout.spacing = 0;
 shell.setLayout(rowLayout);
```

Comment: You can shorten it by setting `rowLayout.marginHeight = 0` and `rowLayout.marginWidth = 0`.